# How to connect django to docker redis container?

Tags: python, django, docker, redis

I am trying to connect django to docker redis container

Here is my docker file

```
FROM        ubuntu:14.04
RUN         apt-get update && apt-get install -y redis-server
EXPOSE      6379
ENTRYPOINT  ["/usr/bin/redis-server"]
```

Here is the result of `docker ps -a`

```
4f7eaeb2761b        /redis          "/usr/bin/redis-serve"   16 hours ago        Up 16 hours               6379/tcp            redis
```

Here is a quick sanity check that redis is working inside docker container

```
 docker exec -ti redis bash

 root@4f7eaeb2761b:/# redis-cli ping
 PONG
 root@4f7eaeb2761b:/# redis-cli
 127.0.0.1:6379> exit
```

Here is my Django `settings.py`

```
CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'redis_cache.RedisCache',
        'LOCATION': 'localhost:6379',
    },
}
```

Here is my view

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.template import loader
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views.decorators.cache import cache_page

@cache_page(60 * 15)
def index(request):
    template = loader.get_template('./index.html')

    return HttpResponse(template.render())
```

Here is alternative redis access

```
import redis

def index(request):
    r = redis.StrictRedis(host='localhost', port=6379, db=0)
    print r # this line doesn't cause error
    r.set('foo', 'bar') # this line cause error

    template = loader.get_template('./index.html')

    return HttpResponse(template.render())
```

I verified that everything work without the `@cache_page` decorator

When I used decorator I am getting

```
Error 61 connecting to localhost:6379. Connection refused.
```

I am not sure how do I expose the docker container besides setting `Expose` port, any help would be appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The thing to understand here is that the container exposed ports != system exposed ports.

The Docker container for redis is exposing the port 6379 from the container -- that is not the same port in the host system.

Assuming you're running docker with:

```
docker run -ti redis bash
```

By default, Docker will choose a random port in the host to bind to the port the container is exposing. You can check the host ports with the command (will show nothing if no port is exposed):

```
docker port CONTAINER_ID
```

Instead, you'll want to run it like this:

```
docker run -ti redis bash -p 6379:6379
```

This tells Docker to link the 6379 host port to the 6379 container port. Then docker port will show you something like this:

```
$ docker port CONTAINER_ID
6379/tcp -> 0.0.0.0:6379
```

You can also use a `docker-compose.yml` file to configure this.

### Read more:

- [Brief Primer on Docker networking rules](https://www.ctl.io/developers/blog/post/docker-networking-rules/)
- [Docker Compose documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose)

Comment: thanks for the answer, I am getting `1:C 20 Mar 01:27:11.320 # Fatal error, can't open config file 'bash'` for ` docker run -ti redis bash -p 6379:6379` and `*** FATAL CONFIG FILE ERROR ***` for `docker run -ti redis /bin/bash -p 6379:6379` I am probably missing some step , also I am observing nothing when I used   `docker port redis` however I was able to run `docker restart redis & docker exec -ti redis bash`

Comment: You're getting that error because the entrypoint is set to `/usr/bin/redis-server` in the `Dockerfile`, so when you try run the container with `bash` it is actually trying to run `/usr/bin/redis-server bash` (which tries to find a file called bash to be the configfile for Redis). You can either use CMD instead of ENTRYPOINT, or overwrite the entrypoint at the cmdline with `docker run -p 6379:6379 -ti --entrypoint=bash redis` (the parameters order matter)

Comment: Thanks for the response, I now have my ports at `0.0.0.0:6379->6379/tcp` but I still can't connect to the redis server, I tried binding my redis `bind 0.0.0.0` at `./etc/redis/redis.conf` and start `redis-server` , I verified that it is started by ssh into using another terminal `redis-cli ping` , but the django app is still having problem connecting to the redis

Comment: @Kevin good call on `bind 0.0.0.0`! did the error message for Django connection changed or is it still connection refused?

Comment: thanks for checking in, so I think I actually don't have to bind the port, I found out I should use `docker-machine`'s  ip instead, which you can find out by `docker-machine ip default` and change my redis instance setting to `r = redis.StrictRedis(host='what_ever_docker_machine_ip_is', port=6379, db=0)` , but I do have to set the port using the command you provide `docker run -p 6379:6379 -ti --entrypoint=bash redis` , thanks so much for providing that

Comment: ah cool, so you're using Docker Machine! I haven't tried out that yet. glad to help. :)

Comment: "Containers for the linked service will be reachable at a hostname identical to the alias, or the service name if no alias was specified." Using docker-machine, people will naturally name the container "redis", and then link with "redis". Where's the internal hostname then ? Why is it unreachable ?

Comment: "Each container for a service joins the default network and is both reachable by other containers on that network, and discoverable by them at a hostname identical to the container name." WTF redis :/